EAS local build for iOS failing after adding react-native-firebase/analytics?
I am trying to run @react-native-firebase/analytics in my Expo-managed app. I've followed the official guide and installed required packages, and added the necessary configuration to my app.json.
But when trying to build a dev build for iOS simulator with EAS --local, the build fails. Without --local, it succeeds. Before adding Firebase packages and config, the local build worked fine.
MacOS version: 14.4.1
Xcode version: 15.3
Build command:
eas build --profile development-simulator --platform ios --local

Build log with INSTALL_PODS part of the log and error:
[INSTALL_PODS] Ignoring ffi-1.15.5 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.5
[INSTALL_PODS] Using Expo modules
[INSTALL_PODS] [Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod ExpoModulesCore
[INSTALL_PODS] [Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod React-Core
[INSTALL_PODS] [Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod React-RCTAppDelegate
[INSTALL_PODS] [Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod expo-dev-menu-interface
[INSTALL_PODS] [Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod EXManifests
[INSTALL_PODS] [Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod EXUpdatesInterface
[INSTALL_PODS] [Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod expo-dev-menu
[INSTALL_PODS] [Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod RCT-Folly
[INSTALL_PODS] [Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod glog
[INSTALL_PODS] [Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod expo-dev-launcher
[INSTALL_PODS] [Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod SDWebImage
[INSTALL_PODS] [Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod SDWebImageWebPCoder
[INSTALL_PODS] [Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod SDWebImageAVIFCoder
[INSTALL_PODS] [Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod SDWebImageSVGCoder
[INSTALL_PODS] [Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod EXStructuredHeaders
[INSTALL_PODS] [Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod EASClient
[INSTALL_PODS] [Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod ReachabilitySwift
[INSTALL_PODS] [Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod sqlite3
[INSTALL_PODS] RNFBAnalytics: Using default Firebase/Analytics with Ad Ids. May require App Tracking Transparency. Not allowed for Kids apps.
[INSTALL_PODS] RNFBAnalytics: You may set variable `$RNFirebaseAnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport=true` in Podfile to use analytics without ad ids.
[INSTALL_PODS] Adding a custom script phase for Pod RNFBApp: [RNFB] Core Configuration
[INSTALL_PODS] Auto-linking React Native modules for target `japodiumfrontend`: RNCAsyncStorage, RNFBAnalytics, RNFBApp, RNGestureHandler, RNReanimated, RNSVG, RNScreens, TrueSheet, react-native-maps, react-native-netinfo, react-native-pager-view, react-native-render-html, react-native-safe-area-context, and react-native-webview
[INSTALL_PODS] Framework build type is static framework
[INSTALL_PODS] [Codegen] Generating ./build/generated/ios/React-Codegen.podspec.json
[INSTALL_PODS] [Codegen] generating an empty RCTThirdPartyFabricComponentsProvider
[INSTALL_PODS] Analyzing dependencies
[INSTALL_PODS] Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
[INSTALL_PODS] [Codegen] Found FBReactNativeSpec
[INSTALL_PODS] Fetching podspec for `RCT-Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`
[INSTALL_PODS] RNFBAnalytics: Using default Firebase/Analytics with Ad Ids. May require App Tracking Transparency. Not allowed for Kids apps.
[INSTALL_PODS] RNFBAnalytics: You may set variable `$RNFirebaseAnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport=true` in Podfile to use analytics without ad ids.
[INSTALL_PODS] [Codegen] Found rncore
[INSTALL_PODS] Fetching podspec for `boost` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec`
[INSTALL_PODS] Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
[INSTALL_PODS] Fetching podspec for `hermes-engine` from `../node_modules/react-native/sdks/hermes-engine/hermes-engine.podspec`
[INSTALL_PODS] [Hermes] Using release tarball from URL: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/facebook/react/react-native-artifacts/0.73.6/react-native-artifacts-0.73.6-hermes-ios-debug.tar.gz
[INSTALL_PODS] % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed
[INSTALL_PODS] Time    Time     Time  Current
[INSTALL_PODS]                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
[INSTALL_PODS] 100 16.2M  100 16.2M
[INSTALL_PODS] 0     0  25.8M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 25.8M
[INSTALL_PODS] % Total    % Receive
[INSTALL_PODS] d % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
[INSTALL_PODS]                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
[INSTALL_PODS] 4 12.3M    4  520k    0     0  3078k      0  0:00:04 --:--:--  0:00:04 3063k
[INSTALL_PODS] 100 12.3M  100 12.3M    0     0  23.4M      0 --:-
[INSTALL_PODS] -:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 23.4M
[INSTALL_PODS] ――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
[INSTALL_PODS] ### Command
[INSTALL_PODS] ```
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/bin/pod install
[INSTALL_PODS] ```
[INSTALL_PODS] ### Report
[INSTALL_PODS] * What did you do?
[INSTALL_PODS] * What did you expect to happen?
[INSTALL_PODS] * What happened instead?
[INSTALL_PODS] ### Stack
[INSTALL_PODS] ```
[INSTALL_PODS]    CocoaPods : 1.12.1
[INSTALL_PODS]         Ruby : ruby 3.3.0 (2023-12-25 revision 5124f9ac75) [arm64-darwin22]
[INSTALL_PODS]     RubyGems : 3.5.4
[INSTALL_PODS]         Host : macOS 14.4.1 (23E224)
[INSTALL_PODS]        Xcode : 15.3 (15E204a)
[INSTALL_PODS]          Git : git version 2.15.0
[INSTALL_PODS] Ruby lib dir : /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib
[INSTALL_PODS] Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
[INSTALL_PODS] ```
[INSTALL_PODS] ### Plugins
[INSTALL_PODS] ```
[INSTALL_PODS] cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.5
[INSTALL_PODS] cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
[INSTALL_PODS] cocoapods-search      : 1.0.1
[INSTALL_PODS] cocoapods-trunk       : 1.6.0
[INSTALL_PODS] cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0
[INSTALL_PODS] ```
[INSTALL_PODS] ### Podfile
[INSTALL_PODS] ```ruby
[INSTALL_PODS] require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"`), "scripts/autolinking")
[INSTALL_PODS] require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"`), "scripts/react_native_pods")
[INSTALL_PODS] require 'json'
[INSTALL_PODS] podfile_properties = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join(__dir__, 'Podfile.properties.json'))) rescue {}
[INSTALL_PODS] ENV['RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED'] = podfile_properties['newArchEnabled'] == 'true' ? '1' : '0'
[INSTALL_PODS] ENV['EX_DEV_CLIENT_NETWORK_INSPECTOR'] = podfile_properties['EX_DEV_CLIENT_NETWORK_INSPECTOR']
[INSTALL_PODS] platform :ios, podfile_properties['ios.deploymentTarget'] || '13.4'
[INSTALL_PODS] install! 'cocoapods',
[INSTALL_PODS]   :deterministic_uuids => false
[INSTALL_PODS] prepare_react_native_project!
[INSTALL_PODS] # If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
[INSTALL_PODS] # because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...), which will be excluded. To fix this,
[INSTALL_PODS] # you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` in `react-native.config.js`
[INSTALL_PODS] #
[INSTALL_PODS] # ```js
[INSTALL_PODS] # module.exports = {
[INSTALL_PODS] #   dependencies: {
[INSTALL_PODS] #     ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),
[INSTALL_PODS] #   }
[INSTALL_PODS] # }
[INSTALL_PODS] # ```
[INSTALL_PODS] flipper_config = FlipperConfiguration.disabled
[INSTALL_PODS] if ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == '1' then
[INSTALL_PODS]   # Explicitly disabled through environment variables
[INSTALL_PODS]   flipper_config = FlipperConfiguration.disabled
[INSTALL_PODS] elsif podfile_properties.key?('ios.flipper') then
[INSTALL_PODS]   # Configure Flipper in Podfile.properties.json
[INSTALL_PODS]   if podfile_properties['ios.flipper'] == 'true' then
[INSTALL_PODS]     flipper_config = FlipperConfiguration.enabled(["Debug", "Release"])
[INSTALL_PODS]   elsif podfile_properties['ios.flipper'] != 'false' then
[INSTALL_PODS]     flipper_config = FlipperConfiguration.enabled(["Debug", "Release"], { 'Flipper' => podfile_properties['ios.flipper'] })
[INSTALL_PODS]   end
[INSTALL_PODS] end
[INSTALL_PODS] target 'japodiumfrontend' do
[INSTALL_PODS]   use_expo_modules!
[INSTALL_PODS]   config = use_native_modules!
[INSTALL_PODS]   use_frameworks! :linkage => podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks'].to_sym if podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks']
[INSTALL_PODS]   use_frameworks! :linkage => ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS'].to_sym if ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
[INSTALL_PODS]   use_react_native!(
[INSTALL_PODS]     :path => config[:reactNativePath],
[INSTALL_PODS]     :hermes_enabled => podfile_properties['expo.jsEngine'] == nil || podfile_properties['expo.jsEngine'] == 'hermes',
[INSTALL_PODS]     # An absolute path to your application root.
[INSTALL_PODS]     :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/..",
[INSTALL_PODS]     # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work if enabled
[INSTALL_PODS]     :flipper_configuration => flipper_config
[INSTALL_PODS]   )
[INSTALL_PODS]   post_install do |installer|
[INSTALL_PODS]     react_native_post_install(
[INSTALL_PODS]       installer,
[INSTALL_PODS]       config[:reactNativePath],
[INSTALL_PODS]       :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
[INSTALL_PODS]     )
[INSTALL_PODS]     # This is necessary for Xcode 14, because it signs resource bundles by default
[INSTALL_PODS]     # when building for devices.
[INSTALL_PODS]     installer.target_installation_results.pod_target_installation_results
[INSTALL_PODS]       .each do |pod_name, target_installation_result|
[INSTALL_PODS]       target_installation_result.resource_bundle_targets.each do |resource_bundle_target|
[INSTALL_PODS]         resource_bundle_target.build_configurations.each do |config|
[INSTALL_PODS]           config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
[INSTALL_PODS]         end
[INSTALL_PODS]       end
[INSTALL_PODS]     end
[INSTALL_PODS]   end
[INSTALL_PODS]   post_integrate do |installer|
[INSTALL_PODS]     begin
[INSTALL_PODS]       expo_patch_react_imports!(installer)
[INSTALL_PODS]     rescue => e
[INSTALL_PODS]       Pod::UI.warn e
[INSTALL_PODS]     end
[INSTALL_PODS]   end
[INSTALL_PODS] end
[INSTALL_PODS] ```
[INSTALL_PODS] ### Error
[INSTALL_PODS] ```
[INSTALL_PODS] LoadError - dlopen(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/lib/libruby.3.2.dylib
[INSTALL_PODS]   Referenced from: <862550A8-72EF-3713-8CD4-00EC968256A1> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle
[INSTALL_PODS]   Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/lib/libruby.3.2.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/lib/libruby.3.2.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/lib/libruby.3.2.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libruby.3.2.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libruby.3.2.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/libruby.3.2.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/libruby.3.2.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/libruby.3.2.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libruby.3.2.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libruby.3.2.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache) - /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle
[INSTALL_PODS] <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in `require'
[INSTALL_PODS] <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in `require'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi.rb:5:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
[INSTALL_PODS] <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in `require'
[INSTALL_PODS] <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in `require'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/ethon-0.16.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
[INSTALL_PODS] <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in `require'
[INSTALL_PODS] <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in `require'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
[INSTALL_PODS] <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in `require'
[INSTALL_PODS] <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in `require'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in `download_typhoeus_impl_async'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in `download_and_save_with_retries_async'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in `download_file_async'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in `download_file'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:284:in `ensure_versions_file_loaded'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:208:in `search'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `block in search'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `select'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `search'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:416:in `create_set_from_sources'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:385:in `find_cached_set'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:360:in `specifications_for_dependency'
[INSTALL_PODS] /o
[INSTALL_PODS] pt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:165:in `search_for'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:274:in `block in sort_dependencies'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `each'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_by'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_by!'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_dependencies'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:60:in `block in sort_dependencies'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:77:in `with_no_such_dependency_error_handling'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:59:in `sort_dependencies'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:754:in `push_state_for_requirements'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:744:in `require_nested_dependencies_for'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:727:in `activate_new_spec'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:684:in `attempt_to_activate'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1082:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1080:in `resolve_dependencies'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:125:in `analyze'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:422:in `analyze'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:244:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `resolve_dependencies'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162:in `install!'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
[INSTALL_PODS] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
[INSTALL_PODS] ```
[INSTALL_PODS] ――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
[INSTALL_PODS] [!] Oh no, an error occurred.
[INSTALL_PODS] Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
[INSTALL_PODS] https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=dlopen%28%2Fopt%2Fhomebrew%2FCellar%2Fcocoapods%2F1.12.1%2Flibexec%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.5%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%2C+0x0009%29%3A+Library+not+loaded%3A+%2Fopt%2Fhomebrew%2Fopt%2Fruby%2Flib%2Flibruby.3.2.dylib%0A++Referenced+from%3A+%3C862550A8-72EF-3713-8CD4-00EC968256A1%3E+%2Fopt%2Fhomebrew%2FCellar%2Fcocoapods%2F1.12.1%2Flibexec%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.5%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%0A++Reason%3A+tried%3A+%27%2Fopt%2Fhomebrew%2Fopt%2Fruby%2Flib%2Flibruby.3.2.dylib%27+%28no+such+file%29%2C+%27%2FSystem%2FVolumes%2FPreboot%2FCryptexes%2FOS%2Fopt%2Fhomebrew%2Fopt%2Fruby%2Flib%2Flibruby.3.2.dylib%27+%28no+such+file%29%2C+%27%2Fopt%2Fhomebrew%2Fopt%2Fruby%2Flib%2Flibruby.3.2.dylib%27+%28no+such+file%29%2C+%27%2Fusr%2Flocal%2Flib%2Flibruby.3.2.dylib%27+%28no+such+file%29%2C+%27%2Fusr%2Flib%2Flibruby.3.2.dylib%27+%28no+such+file%2C+not+in+dyld+cache%29%2C+%27%2Fopt%2Fhomebrew%2FCellar%2Fruby%2F3.3.0%2Flib%2Flibruby.3.2.dylib%27+%28no+such+file%29%2C+%27%2FSystem%2FVolumes%2FPreboot%2FCryptexes%2FOS%2Fopt%2Fhomebrew%2FCellar%2Fruby%2F3.3.0%2Flib%2Flibruby.3.2.dylib%27+%28no+such+file%29%2C+%27%2Fopt%2Fhomebrew%2FCellar%2Fruby%2F3.3.0%2Flib%2Flibruby.3.2.dylib%27+%28no+such+file%29%2C+%27%2Fusr%2Flocal%2Flib%2Flibruby.3.2.dylib%27+%28no+such+file%29%2C+%27%2Fusr%2Flib%2Flibruby.3.2.dylib%27+%28no+such+file%2C+not+in+dyld+cache%29+-+%2Fopt%2Fhomebrew%2FCellar%2Fcocoapods%2F1.12.1%2Flibexec%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.5%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle&type=Issues
[INSTALL_PODS] If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
[INSTALL_PODS] https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new
[INSTALL_PODS] Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
[INSTALL_PODS] https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md
[INSTALL_PODS] Don't forget to anonymize any private data!
[INSTALL_PODS] Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil
[INSTALL_PODS] [!] `<PBXResourcesBuildPhase UUID=`13B07F8E1A680F5B00A75B9A`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `75A4D2AD00B04C15BAE8763D` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and the unknown UUID is being discarded.
[INSTALL_PODS] Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
[INSTALL_PODS]
Error: pod install exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (/Users/anesm/.npm/_npx/89fde002d95f40cb/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:42:23)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:633:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5)
    ...
    at spawnAsync (/Users/anesm/.npm/_npx/89fde002d95f40cb/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:7:23)
    at spawn (/Users/anesm/.npm/_npx/89fde002d95f40cb/node_modules/@expo/turtle-spawn/dist/index.js:16:47)
    at installPods (/Users/anesm/.npm/_npx/89fde002d95f40cb/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/dist/ios/pod.js:11:38)
    at /Users/anesm/.npm/_npx/89fde002d95f40cb/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/dist/builders/ios.js:69:41
    at BuildContext.runBuildPhase (/Users/anesm/.npm/_npx/89fde002d95f40cb/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/dist/context.js:98:34)
    at buildAsync (/Users/anesm/.npm/_npx/89fde002d95f40cb/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/dist/builders/ios.js:68:19)
    at async runBuilderWithHooksAsync (/Users/anesm/.npm/_npx/89fde002d95f40cb/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/dist/builders/common.js:12:13)
    at async Object.iosBuilder (/Users/anesm/.npm/_npx/89fde002d95f40cb/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/dist/builders/ios.js:28:16)
    at async buildIosAsync (/Users/anesm/.npm/_npx/89fde002d95f40cb/node_modules/eas-cli-local-build-plugin/dist/ios.js:43:12)
    at async buildAsync (/Users/anesm/.npm/_npx/89fde002d95f40cb/node_modules/eas-cli-local-build-plugin/dist/build.js:59:29)

Build failed
Unknown error. See logs of the Install pods build phase for more information.
npx exited with non-zero code: 1
    Error: build command failed.


Fixed by upgrading cocoa pods and ruby.
